# Sending Signals to Child Processes to Update Value

Tags: c

I am new to the fork() function in C and have been having some problems. I haven't been able to find an answer that I can understand. I have a parent process which takes input from the user to signal a child process to update a value. What I have below is a simplified version of the actual program. I understand that I am not checking return values or anything of the like.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void parentFunc(int *pid);
void childFunc(void);
void countSignal(int signo);

int count = 10000;

int main(void){
    signal(SIGUSR1, countSignal);

    int pid[3];
    // create child processes
    pid[2] = fork();
    if(pid[2] > 0){
        pid[1] = fork();
        if(pid[1] > 0){
            pid[0] = fork();
            if(pid[0] > 0){
                parentFunc(pid);
            }
            else childFunc();
        }
        else childFunc();
    }
    else childFunc();

    return 0;
}

void parentFunc(int *pid){
    signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGUSR2, SIG_DFL);
    int identifier;
    while(1){
        identifier = fgetc(stdin) - '0';
        kill(pid[identifier-1], SIGUSR1);
    }

}

void childFunc(void){
    srand(getpid());
    while(1){
        count -= (rand() % (3001 - 1000) + 1000);
        sleep(5);
    }
}

void countSignal(int signo){
    signal(SIGUSR1, countSignal);
    count += 2000;
    printf("Child %d has been fed by Parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
    printf("New count level: %d\n", count);
}
```

When a child receives a signal, does it then skip the sleep(5) function? The issue I am having is that every time I try to update a value it seems to add 2000 and then immediately subtract the random value instead of subtracting on 5 second intervals.

I would like it to receive signals to add 2000 at any interval but only subtract every 5 seconds. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a child receives a signal, does it then skip the sleep(5) function?

Yes, if the signal is not ignored, it skips the remaining sleep duration. From [`man 3 sleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html), emphasis added:

> DESCRIPTION
> sleep() causes the calling thread to sleep either until the number of real-time seconds specified in seconds have elapsed or **until a signal arrives which is not ignored**.

> RETURN VALUE
> Zero if the requested time has elapsed, or the **number of seconds left** to sleep, if the call was **interrupted by a signal handler**.

With that in mind, consider the following snippet:

```
unsigned seconds = 5;
        
while (seconds)
    seconds = sleep(seconds);
```

For more precision, consider [`man 2 nanosleep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html).

---

*Aside: [`man 7 signal-safety`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) is worth reading to understand what POSIX defines as safe to do inside of a signal handler (does **not** include calling `printf`).*

*See also: [`sig_atomic_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t)*

Comment: Would this still work if seconds = 1?

Comment: What do you mean? You will have to be more specific as to what you define as "working".

Comment: if sleep were interrupted by a signal while sleeping for 1 second, would that return 0 or 1? If it returns 0 that would stop the while loop, correct?

Comment: If it is unclear, the idea is to replace the single call to `sleep` with a loop that continuously calls `sleep` with the remaining seconds, not to replace the outer while loop with my example. An interrupted call of `sleep(1)` should return zero (although this might be up to the implementation, it makes sense to return zero given the resolution its working with). The loop I have shown stops when the return value is zero. If you need a more precise mechanism, consider `nanosleep`, which deals in nanoseconds.